# How to set the minimum time between double clicks?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mate, fedora, mouse-pointer

How to set the minimum time between double clicks (two clicks)? Avoiding single click turns out to be double clicks

Comment: Hi what is your 0S plz..

Comment: many Linux distros.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu go to Settings → Universal Access → Pointing and Clicking

[image]

and adjust the delay to what you require.

Comment: How to do it in commandline? I have many distros.

Comment: @babojovep If you are primarily a command line user I doubt you use the mouse a lot and certainly even more doubtful for double click operations.

Comment: A need to configure something using command line, don't exactly mean that he is a command line user, how about configure a hundred stations ?